# How to return a value from a pointer in C

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have the following code and I would like to return the value of 'out' and print it to a file.  How do I return the value of 'out' instead of the location.  Also, how do I call the function uint32_pack from the main function? Thank you for your help.

```
#if HAVE_PROTOBUF_C_CONFIG_H
#include "protobuf-c-config.h"
#endif
#include <stdio.h>                      /* for occasional printf()s */
#include <stdlib.h>                     /* for abort(), malloc() etc */
#include <string.h>                     /* for strlen(), memcpy(), memmove() */
#if HAVE_ALLOCA_H
#include <alloca.h>
#elif HAVE_MALLOC_H
#include <malloc.h>
#endif

#include "protobuf-c.h"

int main(void){
uint32_t hexvalue = 0x20;
int gnuvalue;
uint8_t fake_out;
  FILE *fp;

  fp = fopen("binarydata.txt","w");
  gnuvalue = uint32_pack (hexvalue, fake_out);
  fprintf(fp,"%x",gnuvalue);
  fclose(fp);
}


/* === pack() === */
/* Pack an unsigned 32-bit integer in base-128 encoding, and return the number of bytes needed:
   this will be 5 or less. */
static inline size_t
uint32_pack (uint32_t value, uint8_t *out)
{
  unsigned rv = 0;

  if (value >= 0x80)
    {
      out[rv++] = value | 0x80;
      value >>= 7;
      if (value >= 0x80)
        {
          out[rv++] = value | 0x80;
          value >>= 7;
          if (value >= 0x80)
            {
              out[rv++] = value | 0x80;
              value >>= 7;
              if (value >= 0x80)
                {
                  out[rv++] = value | 0x80;
                  value >>= 7;
                }
            }
        }

  /* assert: value<128 */
  out[rv++] = value;
  return &out;
  }
}
```

Comment: I get the following errors now, "conflicting types for 'uint32_pack'" at line 56 and "previous implicit declaration of 'uint32_pack' was here" at ling43

Comment: You have to declare the function before you use it. It seems like you should brush up on the basics of C.

Comment: Indeedy.  Methinks @Sam should go ahead and post his comment as an answer, since his comment actually precedes all of our answers as well.

Comment: gnuvalue is declare int, `return *out` would return uint8_t; though this is not problematic, it could be a clue that you arent doing what you mean

Answer (score 1):

You want to dereference the pointer using the `*` unary operator, like so:

```
return *out;
```

Doing this, it'll return the value stored at the location pointed to by `out`.

Answer (score 0):

You should return `*out`. And update the comment to reflect this. In practice it seems like `out` should fit in a `size_t` (i.e. `sizeof size_t` will be large enough) but it is hack-ish to assume it.

On calling from main, the current way won't work because `fake_out` is an `uint8_t`, not an `uint8_t*`. Of course `&fakeout` will crash so don't do that, you have to allocate a large enough array of `uint8_t`.

Answer (score 0):

There something odd in your code here

```
  uint8_t fake_out;
  gnuvalue = uint32_pack (hexvalue, fake_out);
```

while the prototype for uint32_pack needs `uint8_t *`, so it should be `&fake_out`. And then to return it, you need just to dereference the pointer to modify fake_out,something like `*out = value;`.

If you need to return two values (gnuvalue and fake_out), this is how you can.

Another option could be to return a pointer to a struct malloc-ed in the function (then you need to free it soon or later), and the struct holds both "gnuvalue" and "fake_out".